# Fatal signal 11 - Crash every time I exit the android google map activity

Tags: android, crash, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an new test app with a google map activity in Android Studio. All my project was created by the wizard and the only file I had to change a bit was build.gradle to fix some version numbers. I run it in the emulator (Google APIs level 19, android 4.4.2, x86 system image), the app works, the api-key is correct, the map is displayed. However any time I exit the activity (the app) it gets crashed:

```
10-02 20:55:21.550    8300-8375/android.example.com.map A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x006f0069 (code=1), thread 8375 (Thread-369)
10-02 20:55:21.680      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-02 20:55:21.680      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/google_sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.2/KK/1314097:eng/test-keys'
10-02 20:55:21.680      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
10-02 20:55:21.680      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 8300, tid: 8375, name: Thread-369  >>> android.example.com.map <<<
10-02 20:55:21.680      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 006f0069
10-02 20:55:21.820      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr 006f0069:
10-02 20:55:21.820      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map below)
10-02 20:55:21.820      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
10-02 20:55:21.830      931-931/? I/DEBUG﹕ a4d68000-a4d81000 r-- /system/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
10-02 20:55:21.870    1272-1294/system_process I/BootReceiver﹕ Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-02 20:55:21.880      934-934/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 8300 terminated by signal (11)
10-02 20:55:21.880    1272-1416/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Process android.example.com.map (pid 8300) has died.
```

build.gradle (had to change compileSdkVersion to 19, com.google.android.gms:play-services to 5.0.+, all the rest of this file and all the other files below are output of the wizard):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.map"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
}
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
package android.example.com.map;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

google_maps_api.xml:

```
<resources>
        <string name="google_maps_key_instructions" templateMergeStrategy="replace"></string>    
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">AIza...</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.example.com.map" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: I recently had the same issue, but for me was generated by BluetoothSocket: I was trying to read the InputStream associated with the socket, when this was already closed

Comment: A hard crash like this is indicative of a bug in the device or emulator, more so than in your code. If you are not using the NDK, there is nothing at the Java level that should result in a `SIGSEGV`. If you can create a sample project that reproduces the error, you might wish to file a bug on the Maps issue tracker. You might also wish to see if you crash on hardware, or if this is just a problem with the emulator.

Comment: I just did that: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7200 If anyone else has similar problems please add details there and don't forget to click the star icon to indicate you're also interested in the issue being rerolved